# Replace PrimaryKeyRelatedField with another field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models which consist in a `User` model and a `Present` one. A `User` can have multiple `Present` but a `Present` has a unique `User`:

My `models.py` is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Present(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.FloatField()
    link = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    isAlreadyBought = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='presents', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My `serializers.py` are:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from blog.models import Present, Location
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    presents = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Present.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'presents')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        if 'password' in validated_data:
                user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
                user.save()
        return user



class PresentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), read_only=False, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Present
        fields = ('name', 'link', 'price', 'isAlreadyBought', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Present.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Currently, if I want to get the all the presents associate with a given User, I use the primary key (in `views.py`):

```
class PresentsOfUser(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Present.objects.all().filter(user=33)
    serializer_class = PresentSerializer
```

However, I would rather use the `username` field of the `User` instead of the primary key.

I have tried using a `SlugRelatedField` but I am not sure this is the right way to achieve my goal:

```
class PresentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='username', read_only=False, many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Present
        fields = ('name', 'link', 'price', 'isAlreadyBought', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Present.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

And with this modification, I now use the following `View` to get the user `'Marcel'` whose `id` is `33`:

```
class PresentsOfUser(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Present.objects.all().filter(user='Marcel')
    serializer_class = PresentSerializer
```

But in this case, I get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Marcel'
```

But if I replace `user='Marcel'` by `user=33` (as previously), I get:

```
[{"name":"Nintendo","link":"fake_link","price":50.8,"isAlreadyBought":true,"user":"Marcel"},{"name":"Gamecube","link":"fake_link","price":50.8,"isAlreadyBought":true,"user":"Marcel"}]
```

where the user field is now the `username` and not the user's `id`.

However, I do not understand why filtering with `user='Marcel'` fails...

Comment: Have you tried `'user__username'` in the fields of the present serializer?

Comment: Could you detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is w/ this line:

`queryset = Present.objects.all().filter(user='Marcel')`

With the assumption `Marcel` is username with `pk` => `33`

You can't filter using a string, instead something like this:

`queryset = Present.objects.all().filter(user__username='Marcel')`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` or `SlugRelatedField` in my Present serializer?

Comment: If you want 'username' instead of 'pk' value.. you would use 'SlugRelatedField'.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up by overriding the `get_queryset`method while keeping the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` in my serializer (with `user__username='Marcel'`as mishbah suggested):

```
class PresentsOfUser(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = PresentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Optionally restricts the returned purchases to a given user,
        by filtering against a `username` query parameter in the URL.
        """
        queryset = Present.objects.all()
        username = self.kwargs['user']
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user__username=username)

        if len(queryset) == 0:
            raise Http404

        return queryset
```

It also works when replacing `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` by `SlugRelatedField`:

```
user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='username', read_only=False, many=False)
```

and adding `to_field='username'`in the `ForeignKey` of my `Present` model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='presents', to_field='username', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```